# Is there a way to activate in-app purchasing on Words With Friends for the Kindle Fire?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

I have Words With Friends, version 6.7.1 that I downloaded from the Amazon app store on the device.  The version I have on my Android phone has in-app purchasing enabled, such that one can get the ads free version, etc.

After hunting around on the Kindle Fire version, I can't for the life of me figure out how to enable the in-app purchasing for removing the ads and getting statistics.  I have emailed Zynga at least 3 times inquiring about it, but I have never received a reply from them.

Does this feature exist in the Kindle Fire version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, 3/23/14, to commemorate the 3rd anniversary of the Amazon App Store, Zynga has released a version for the Kindle Fire with in-app purchasing.

The UI for the updated app mimics the version that had been already available in the Google Play store.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are currently no in-app purchases available (as of Feb. 11th 2014). If you read the [reviews](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064X7B4A) on Amazon, you're not the only one who'd like to pay to get an ad-free version, but it's not available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm going to wait a bit and see if anyone happens to have any further info as to why.

Comment: That is up to the developer. Google Play Store and Amazon App Store have separate In-App purchasing implementations, so they can't use the same code as in the Google Play Store version.